# If there is a record under a key with a value, do not select that key

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I am trying to find a way in CR2013 to only select records if every record under a key does not have a value. I don't see a way to use the SQL: NOT EXIST in CR.

I've tried to create group selections, which seem to be the best way to go with this, to match these requirements but I cannot.

Basically, if this is my table below:

```
Jobid    Transaction    Type       JTD_COST
1        3/31/16        1          1000.00
1        4/1/16         2          500.00
2        6/1/16         1          1000.00
```

I want to display only the contents, summed, of an entire key if any record in that key does not have a type of 2.

When I use group formulas, I still get all the records that have the intermediate transaction amount.  How can I do this?

Comment: which column is the key here?

Comment: It's a composite key, that deals with, say JobID, Transaction date and Type.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this way:

Create a formula `@concat`combining all 3 fields and convert to string.

```
ToText(Jobid)&ToText(Transaction)&ToText(Type);
```

Now use this to group the report.

Now in supress of the group header, group footer and details(if you use) use the following condition

```
Not(2 in {@Concat})
```

Let me know incase any issue

Comment: Wouldn't this look for "2" in my key, and not post if it was found?  What if 2 was in my key, but not in the Transaction field?  Such as a date?  This solution actually works for me, but could be an issue with other usages.

Comment: What are other combinations you are looking for

Comment: In my case, I am looking for all records with certain text in the description of a transaction, not listed on my sample.  I found a different way to go about this, but not the way I phrased my question.  I'm not sure it's possible without a crazy work around.

Comment: If you found the way post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

How I ended up getting this data:

Outside of CR 2013, I queried for Distinct jobs where the conditions were met.  On these records, I wrote a Boolean TRUE to a new field.  Now I can filter for this condition in & out of reports - however I still see the need for it.  If someone can submit a better answer, I'd appreciate it.